# How can I sort packages by ratings / downloads in Ubuntu Software Centre?

Tags: software-center

I wanted to see which packages in certain category are most popular in order to try them. Is that possible to accomplish in Ubuntu Software Centre? I didn't see any sorting capabilities there, unfortunately. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible at the moment. Additionally, in my USC, ratings only appear in the software list when I click on a single application.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I'm glad I thought about this cool idea! :)

Comment: Could should file a bug report and propose this as an enhancement

Comment: If something **so obvious** is not implemented, naturally, I wonder if this was omitted on purpose, you know...

Answer (score 1):

I [wrote a script](http://linuxonly.nl/docs/56/155_Sort_Ubuntu_packages_by_popularity.html) which sorts the output of apt-cache on popularity:

```
$ apt-cache search twitter client | ./popsort.py
gwibber - microblogging client for GNOME
pidgin-microblog - Microblogging plugins for Pidgin
choqok - KDE micro-blogging client
hotot - lightweight microblogging client
qwit - Lightweight desktop client for Twitter microblogging service
$
```